# Can the contingency spell trigger a cantrip?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

Can the *contingency* spell trigger a cantrip?  Ex. Could your death trigger *spare the dying*?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, *contingency* can trigger cantrips, including *spare the dying* (assuming you can cast it).

> Choose a spell of 5th level or lower that you can cast, that
>   has a casting time of 1 action, and that can target you.

Cantrips are level 0 spells:

> A cantrip’s
>   spell level is 0.

So they are spells of lower than 5th level. The *spare the dying* cantrip has a casting time of 1 action, and can target you, so as long as you can cast it, it's a valid choice for *contingency*.

You should note, though, that it needs to be triggered by you reaching 0 hit points, not by your death.

> You touch a living creature that has 0 hit points. The
>   creature becomes stable.

If you've died, it's too late for *spare the dying* to help you. It needs to be triggered while you're still dying in order to save you.

Comment: While this is the intuitive solution (+1), [recent discussion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124707/can-i-select-a-spell-that-doesnt-use-a-slot-as-a-contingent-spell/124710) leads me to question whether this is true (but not reject outright) since *contingency* hints at needing to expend a spell slot. You may want to consider that with your answer here or weigh in over there.